# Sum only for Employee ID's present in latest snapshot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with a row per month for each employee working in our company. So, if employee A has been working for our company from July 2016 till now, this person has approx. 24 rows (one row for each month she was in service).

I'm trying to summarize the experience each of the current employees have in a particular function. So, if employee A has worked 6 months in Sales and 18 months in Marketing, then I count the number of rows this employee has Sales or Marketing in the column indicating the function.

I have created a code which does seems to count the functional experience per employee, but it double counts data. It does not take the latest snapshot as starting point.

```
SELECT A.EMPLOYEE_ID,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.FUNCTION_CODE ='CUS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EXP_CUS,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.FUNCTION_CODE ='MKT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EXP_MKT
FROM [dbname].[AGL_V_HRA_FE_R].[VW_HRA_EMPLOYEE_DETAIL] AS A INNER JOIN [dbname].[AGL_V_HRA_FE_R].[VW_HRA_EMPLOYEE_DETAIL] AS B ON A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE B.WORKLEVEL_CODE > '1'
GROUP BY A.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

I expected the output for employee A to be EXP_CUS = 6 and EXP_MKT = 18. Instead, the output for both is much higher as it is double counting rows. When I add the line AND B.SNAPSHOT_DATE = '2019-06-30', the output is correct. I don't like to manually adjust the code every month and rather refer to the latest snapshot date.

**ADDED**
The original table looks like this

```
SNAPSHOT_DATE | EMPLOYEE_ID | FUNCTION_CODE
2019-06-30    | 000000001   | CUS
2019-06-30    | 000000002   | MKT
2019-05-31    | 000000001   | CUS
2019-05-31    | 000000002   | MKT
2019-04-30    | 000000001   | MKT
2019-04-30    | 000000002   | MKT
```

The desired output would be

```
EMPLOYEE_ID   | EXP_CUS     | EXP_MKT
000000001     | 2           | 1
000000002     | 0           | 3
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output for all tables involved.

Comment: you have duplcate EMPLOYEE_ID in your one of the tables which makes count data double ,share your tables data which will help to identify problem

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen and Zaynul. I've updated my initial post to reflect the original database and my desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PIVOT to get your desired result as below-

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,
ISNULL([CUS],0) AS [EXP_CUS],
ISNULL([MKT],0) AS [EXP_MKT]
FROM 
(
    SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,FUNCTION_CODE,COUNT(SNAPSHOT_DATE)  T
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID,FUNCTION_CODE
)P
PIVOT(
    SUM(T)
    FOR FUNCTION_CODE IN ([CUS],[MKT])
)PVT
```

Output is-

```
EMPLOYEE_ID EXP_CUS EXP_MKT
000000001   2       1
000000002   0       3
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are using a self join.  This seems to do what you want:

```
SELECT ED.EMPLOYEE_ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ED.FUNCTION_CODE ='CUS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EXP_CUS,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ED.FUNCTION_CODE ='MKT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EXP_MKT
FROM [dbname].[AGL_V_HRA_FE_R].[VW_HRA_EMPLOYEE_DETAIL] ed 
WHERE ED.WORKLEVEL_CODE > '1'
GROUP BY ED.EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

If you only want employees with the most recent snapshot date, then you can use window functions:

```
SELECT ED.EMPLOYEE_ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ED.FUNCTION_CODE ='CUS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EXP_CUS,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ED.FUNCTION_CODE ='MKT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EXP_MKT
(SELECT ED.*,
        MAX(SNAPSHOT_DATE) OVER () as OVERALL_MAX_SNAPSHOT_DATE,
        MAX(SNAPSHOT_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID) as EMPLOYEE_MAX_SNAPSHOT_DATE            
 FROM [dbname].[AGL_V_HRA_FE_R].[VW_HRA_EMPLOYEE_DETAIL] ED
) ED
WHERE ED.WORKLEVEL_CODE > '1' AND
      EMPLOYEE_MAX_SNAPSHOT_DATE = OVERALL_MAX_SNAPSHOT_DATE
GROUP BY ED.EMPLOYEE_ID;
```